# Bringing the image in front of background?

Tags: html, css, css-position, psd

I am using css positioning to set the position of an image above the header background. but it isn't working.

Here is the psd image of what i want to achieve:

[image]

> Note:- Here in the image i am talking about the header background and
>   the green bar with shadow at the top.

Html code:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
          <div class="header-shadow"></div>
          <hgroup></hgroup>
          <nav role="navigation" class="site-navigation main-navigation">

          </nav><!-- .site-navigation .main-navigation -->
    </header><!-- #masthead .site-header -->
```

CSS code:-

```
.site-header{
    position: relative;
    background: url('../images/background.jpg') repeat-x;
    height: 176px;
}
.header-shadow{
    position: absolute;
    background: url('../images/header-shade.jpg') repeat-x;
    height:31px;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have taken the `.header-shadow` out of the flow of the page. It doesn't therefore take on the width of its parent. Set `width:100%`:

```
.header-shadow {
    position: absolute;
    background: url('../images/header-shade.jpg') repeat-x;
    height:31px;
    width:100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FFS4V/)

Or even better; don't position it absolutely at all:

```
.header-shadow {
    background: url('../images/header-shade.jpg') repeat-x;
    height:31px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FFS4V/1)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the left css attribute e.g.

```
left:0px;
```

You could also try defining the width and height of the image within the css although this should normally be worked out by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help, use ,header-shadow -> position as relative, it will work fine

```
.site-header{
position: relative;
background: url('../images/background.jpg') repeat-x;
height: 176px;
}
.header-shadow{
 position: relative;
background: url('../images/header-shade.jpg') repeat-x;
height:31px;
width:100%;
top: 0;
left:0;
}
```